# Query Dynamo DB with multiple columns using AWS SDK V3 and Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have the below piece of code that I try to use to fetch a row of data using values for 3 columns.

```
const client = new DynamoDB({region: "us-east-1"});
const params = {
TableName: Tables.TYPES,
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#type': "type",
    '#region': "region",
    '#dock': "dock"
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":type": type,
    ":dock": dock,
    ":region": region
 },
 KeyConditionExpression: '#type = :type AND #dock = :dock AND #region = :region'
 }
 let types: Record<string, NativeAttributeValue> = data = await client.send(new QueryCommand(params));
 console.log("Received data ", data);
```

However when I run the above code I get the following error.

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I read the row using values for multiple columns in my Dynamo DB table? I am using `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb` by the way. Appreciate any help.

UPDATE:
Still not working:

```
const params = {
            TableName: Tables. TYPES,
            FilterExpression: 'type = :type AND dock = :dock AND region = :region',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":type": {S: type},
                ":dock": {S: dock},
                ":region": {s: region}
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can have one partition / hash and optionally one range / sort key. You cannot query based on three columns.

Comment: You can use a FilterExpression on the non-key attribute(s).

Comment: @jarmod do I have to use ScanCommand with FilterExpression then?

Comment: No, and you generally want to avoid scans, of course. Server-side [filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/interfaces/querycommandinput.html#filterexpression) are available on queries.

Comment: BTW you passed `params` to the `QueryCommand` constructor but `params` is undefined (at least in the code I see), which is likely what's causing the runtime error.

Comment: @jarmod updated the code with FilterExpression but still getting the same error. `params` was actually a copy paste error, apologies.

Comment: You've converted the 3-attribute key condition expression into a 3-attribute filter expression, which is not a valid query. I'm assuming that 1 or 2 of those attributes are keys (pk and optionally sk). You need both key condition and filter expressions. Include the key attributes in the former, and the non-key attributes in the latter.

Comment: @AnOldSoul - could you clarify which keys are in your Primary key?

Comment: All my columns are non-unique and therefore I ended up using a Guid for partition key. Can I only use a sort key for KeyConditionExpression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyConditionExpression` is for keys only, your partition key and sort key. Outside of that, if you wish to filter on non key attributes you must use `FilterExpression`.

Assuming `type` is your Partition key, the params would look like this (edit further to suit your specific needs):

```
const params = {
TableName: Tables.TYPES,
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#type': "type",
    '#region': "region",
    '#dock': "dock"
},
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":type": type,
    ":dock": dock,
    ":region": region
 },
 KeyConditionExpression: "#type = :type",
 FilterExpression: "#dock = :dock AND #region = :region"
 }
```

Comment: All my columns are non-unique and therefore I ended up using a Guid for partition key. Is there a way to query without using a KeyConditionExpression?

Comment: For that you would remove the `KeyConditionExpression` and keep your non key values in `FilterExpression` and use the `Scan` API. A GUID is rarely useful as a partition key in DynamoDB.